# Define PHP function that will use arrays from $_POST as arguments?

Tags: php, function, post

I am trying to define a function that will use arrays in $_POST as arguments, but something is not working. Here is what I have: Any ideas why is not working? Thanks.

```
function variables_set ($Array1, $Array2, $DayOfWeek) {
    if (isset($Array2)) {
        $DayOfWeek=array_unique($Array2); //Remove duplicate values in the array
    } else {
        $DayOfWeek=$Array1;                             
    }
}

variables_set ($_POST['selectM'], $_POST['hiddenM'], $Monday); //Call the function
```

Comment: If `$Array2` is an array, then what do you think `isset($Array2)` will accomplish?

Comment: @dbf do you mean the one on the far right, right below the `q` in `unique`?

Comment: *"Something is not working"* - Well, what is not working? You need to properly describe your programming problem.

Comment: From your function body I would presume you were trying to make one parameter return the result per reference. Add a `&` before `$DayOfWeek` in the function declaration. Better yet, make it the `return` value and assign it in the call.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `isset()` seems ambiguous to me, because as soon as you try passing a non-set variable a notice is thrown. Consider the code below:

```
function test($a){
    echo '$a is' . (isset($a) ? '' : 'not').' set';
}

echo '$b is' . (isset($b) ? '' : 'not').' set';
test($b); // Notice: Undefined variable: b
```

Also note that this is the same with indices, like in your case.

---

**Edit:** The following code is the way it should look like:

```
function test($a){
    if(!is_null($a)){
        // do something with $a
    }
}

test(isset($_POST['selectM']) ? $_POST['selectM'] : null);
```